# UITableViewCell reorganize subviews when the 'delete' button appears

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

Does anyone knows any method to resize subviews(I.E. UILabelView) when `Delete` button appears.

There could be two methods:

1.Capture a notification, if there's one, when the button appears in the UITableViewCell
2.Tell the framework re-arange it automatically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your  UITableViewCell class's .m file use layoutSubviews. It is called every time the cell is resized, the delete button appears/disappears, and more:

```
- (void) layoutSubviews {

    [super layoutSubviews];


    frame = self.contentView.bounds; ///this is the availalbe space for the cell
    ///it's automatically adjusted when the delte button appears
    ///so use it to resize all of your interface elements
}
```

You can also use `if (self.editing) {` inside of layoutSubviews for more control.