# UITableView delete button overlaps to content

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, xib

I'm preparing a `UITableView` with a custom prototype cell having a `UISwitch` widget on the right side, and I'd like to let my users be able to delete rows.

Everything is fine with that, except the fact that when the delete button shows up it overlaps   to the `UISwitch`, this way:

[image: Delete button overlapping to UISwitch]

Is it possible to have the `UISwitch` shifting left when the delete button appears?

---

### Epilogue

I've decided for brevity to not shift my `UISwitch` position when "delete" button appears, but to make it disappear, bringing it back when the "delete" button is gone.

So, according to @geo suggestion (thank you), I've managed it out (quite simply) this way:

In my `UITableViewCell`' subclass `.m` file:

```
- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state
{
    [super willTransitionToState:state];
    if (state & UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask) {
        activationSwitch.hidden = YES;
    }
    else {
        activationSwitch.hidden = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1929629/730701).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Override the Methode

```
-(void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state
```

-> `UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask`
of your custom Cell and do there your customizing :)

Answer (score 0):

I hit a very similar problem and fixed it. You need the right autoresizing mask (assuming not doing auto layout here) for your UI elements in your custom tableview cell in Interface Builder.

In my case, I needed to add the Left constraint (see that little autoresizing picture/animation in the Size Inspector, View section) for each of my UI elements.

Add a Left "bar", and you should be good.